# Numpy FFT of Gaussian does not give Gaussian

Tags: numpy, fft

According to my good friend [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformGaussian.html), the Fourier transform of a Gaussian in the temporal/spatial domain gives another Gaussian in the frequency/spectral domain. When I put this to the test using the `numpy.fft.fft` routine, I don't exactly get what I expected.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 1000    # Number of samples
a = 10.0    # Inverse variance
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, N)   # Spatial domain
y = np.exp(-a*x**2)         # Gaussian in spatial domain

dx = x[1] - x[0]            # Sampling rate
k = np.fft.fftfreq(N, dx)   # Wave numbers
inds = np.argsort(k)        # Sorting order of wave numbers

# Analytical solution for Fourier transform of y
y_hat = np.sqrt(np.pi / a) * np.exp(-np.pi**2 * k**2 / a)
# Numerical solution (FFT of y)
y_hat2 = np.fft.fft(y)

# Plot original function in spatial domain
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel("position [m]")
plt.ylabel("y")

# Plot solutions in the spectral domain
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(k[inds], np.real(y_hat2[inds]), label="Real FFT(y)")
plt.plot(k[inds], np.imag(y_hat2[inds]), label="Imag FFT(y)")
plt.plot(k[inds], y_hat[inds], "k--", label="Analytical")
plt.xlabel("wave number [1/m]")
plt.ylabel("FFT(y)")
plt.ylim((-1, 1))
plt.xlim((-5, 5))
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

As it turns out, the imaginary part of the FFT of `y` is nonzero, and the real part oscillates wildly around 0, both of which are not expected from the analytical solution. Could anyone explain to me why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

For a canonical FFT result to be strictly real, the input must be (circularly) symmetric around the first element in the FFT input array.  Your input seems to be symmetric around the middle of the input array, which modulates the FFT result (time shift property).

Try an FFTShift operation.

Comment: When I do `fft(fftshift(y))`, I still get a nonzero imaginary component.

Comment: If I define `y_shift = np.fft.fftshift(y)`, then `y_shift - y_shift[::-1]` is zero for all elements (within numerical precision). When I increase `N`, the amplitude of the real component increases while the amplitude of the imaginary component remains constant. Shouldn't the outcome of `fft` be independent of the number of samples?

Comment: vector == vector backwards is NOT circularly symmetric around element 0.  One off.  Also check to make sure imaginary components aren't zero when rounding to some reasonable quantization.  Not rounded == numerical noise.